# No More Mixed Messages About HTTPS

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, https, mixed-content

Till chrome 81, I was able to display mix images on my website. means that HTTPS was able to load HTTP subresources. Chrome just notified me about mixed content and showed a “Not Secure” chip in the omnibox.

But now, they are blocking it completely. It won't load mix images and request will be upgraded to HTTPS automatically.

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/img1"/>


Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS.
```

Is there any way I can avoid the automatic upgrade?

Comment: Well i have the same problem now, any news on this?